# How can I reference an image in GitLab markdown in the current directory with the path starting with ./ dot slash?

Tags: image, markdown, gitlab

I have stored a Markdown file and an image file in a Git repo as follows:

- `readme.markdown`
- `images/`

  - `image.png`

I reference the image from `readme.markdown` like this:

```
![](./images/image.png)
```

This renders as expected in ReText, but does not render when I push the repo to GitLab.

How can I reference the image from the Markdown file so that it renders when viewed in GitLab?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`![](images/image.png)` without the `./` works for me: https://gitlab.com/cirosantilli/test/blob/bffbcc928282ede14dcb42768f10a7ef21a665f1/markdown.md#image

I have opened a request for this to be allowed at: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6746307-support-markdown-image-path-in-current-directory-s , but it entered into Internet void when GitLab dumped UserVoice.

Comment: That's true. I retry without the `./` and it works. I edit my post

Comment: What about defining the a custom image size (hxw)?

Comment: @danger89 docs say nothing https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/markdown/markdown.md so I'd assume impossible. So either HTML inside markdown (seems to allow it: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#WHITELIST-constant) or ImageMagick it.

Answer (score 20):

### Similar problem with Gitlab & Images in readme.md

I had the same problem with my Logo inside of a readme.md in my Extension and with Gitlab (running on a Ubuntu-Server).

Ubuntu Version: 16.04.2 LTS

Gitlab Version: 10.3.4 56dc722

### My Solution

You can also use a snippet for image-usage in your readme.md by simply following these steps:

#### In the Overview of Gitlab (Logged in)

1. Go to the project where your want to use that image
2. in the topnavigation on the right click the **+ button**
3. **UNDER YOUR PROJECT** click **new snippet** in the dropdown

#### In the **new snippet form**

1. Type a **title**
2. On the bottom right corner of the RTE-Field click **Attach a file**
3. **Select** your **file** and press **Open**
4. Click the **checkbox Public**
5. **name the snippet** (under the Checkboxes) [the field beside the **1** not the "header"]
6. Click **Create Snippet**

#### Troubleshooting

If you get the following error you forgot point 5:

> The form contains the following error:
>
> Content can't be blank

### Now we have a working Imagelink

Now, if you edit the snippet again, you can copy the Image-Code looks like this:

`![Alt-Text](/uploads/472fc65e1a1bc11b355cc03d6c339fd5/logo_.svg)`

to your readme.md file.

If you like to use a link also, it has to look like that:

`[![Alt-Text](/uploads/4013547485b9e88e98f1af3870116a29/logo_mit_claim.svg)](https://your-destination.com)`

Hope it helps other ppls

Comment: Dont works for me. Neither the snippet contains the image. If I click on the link my browser ask to save as text file: `image.svg.txt`, and dont show the image

Comment: Finally I found that your workaround also works for me, just there was another issue in my case: My svg file was exported by inkscape, which works well in local markdown documents, but I need to set plain svg to use in gitlab.

Comment: While interesting, I don't think this meets the author's request.  They seem to want to keep their document self-contained and want version control to maintain the link between the specific image file and the specific document.  Your solution is basically using GitLab Snippets as a file hosting service for your image file.

Comment: Also I don't think this solution works if anyone other than the author themself (while logged in and authenticated to GitLab) wants to view the file.  The Snippet has permissioned access that limits who can get to the file that's completely separated from the repo itself.

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to your project
2. Select issues
3. Create new issue
4. In the new issue description, click on attach file
5. Browse to your file and attach
6. A link in the form "[image: filename]"
   will be generated on the description pane.
7. Copy the link and paste it in your readme.md file
8. Do not submit the issue unless you had intended to.

Comment: This solution (with a modification) is the one I prefer, because it allows copy + paste to add an image to the Readme.md      In short, In an Issue : 1)  generate a URL for the image  and then 2) copy and paste the new URL to the Readme.md (in edit mode) and 3) with preview mode in the Readme.md file the image will display.

Comment: Your solution is basically to mis-use the GitLab Issue system to get GitLab to act as a file server for the image.  The author seems to want linked version control and self-contained documents or they could have added the image to any cloud storage as a publicly shared file or something similar.  While this solution is interesting, I don't think it satisfies the request.

Comment: This works to host your image on Gitlab's servers, but just a word of caution that you won't know how Gitlab's cleanup policy works, e.g. will they automatically clean up unreferenced images / images uploaded but were eventually not attached in an issue, so the best bet would still be to store your images somewhere more permanent

Answer (score 6):

My images where in the `.bin/img/` folder. 
I had to use below format to get an image:

```
![alt text](<./bin/img/some_image.png>)
```

Mind the `<>`

Comment: The pointed brackets seem to be required at least for gitlab 9.1.4

Comment: The correct answer! This is better than omitting ./ which does work but would make the reference absolute to the repository root. Using <./...> however also works in subdirectories.