# GitLab: How to embed image from repo in the wiki?

Tags: gitlab, gollum-wiki

I have a GitLab repository with documentation in the attached wiki (i.e. NOT in the repo itself) and an image file *inside the repository itself* that I want to embed in wiki pages.

How can this be done?

From a wiki page, I can successfully link to the image using
`[[../tree/master/pathto/myimage.jpg]]` or `[[../raw/master/pathto/myimage.jpg]]` but

`![](../raw/master/pathto/myimage.jpg)`

doesn't seem to work.

(GitLab Community Edition 10.0.3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reference an image in GitLab markdown in the current directory with the path starting with ./ dot slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016052/how-can-i-reference-an-image-in-gitlab-markdown-in-the-current-directory-with-th)

Comment: @YSelf, it's not a duplicate: The other question deals with embedding an image from the documentation _within_ the repo itself. What I'm looking for is doing so from the associated wiki, which afaik is a separate repository under the hood.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Most probably it currently does not work, since .. seem to be removed by the [markdown parser](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/), although they would be valid in URLs. You could open a issues at gitlab.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Embedding using the *absolute* path to the repo and image worked:

`![](https://url.of.my.repo/raw/master/pathto/myimage.jpg)`

Comment: I'd still be interested in finding out a way using some relative path, in case the repo location ever moves.

Answer (score 2):

Use the '*Attach a file*' button from the wiki page:

[image]

It is a triggy operation but sometimes it works :) and you find your attached image:

[image]

Comment: The photo uploaded this way is not added to the repo, but the repo of the wiki.