# How to create imagemap in gitlab markdown file

Tags: html, svg, gitlab, markdown

## The Desired result :

a clickable image in a markdown-file on the gitlab platform.

### Attempt 1 : SVG - Built in links - with markdown code

it is possible to implement urls in an svg file.
   I inserted the links with inkscape. When i open the image     with the browser the image works as a clickable image.

I inserted the image in the markdown-file :

```
 ![](img/myimage.svg)
```

#### Result

- The image is not displayed

### Attempt 2 : SVG as a link

```
 [link to image](img/myimage.svg)
```

#### Result

- a download-dialogbox to download the file

### Attempt 3 : SVG - html - imagemap

```
    <!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
    <img src="img/myimage.svg" usemap="#image-map">

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="_blank" alt="index" title="index" href="http://www.example.com" coords="84,35,214,71" shape="rect">
    </map>
```

#### Result

- image is visible in the markdown file
- a download-dialogbox  appears when clicking the image

### Attempt 4 : PNG File - html- imagemap

uploading svg like mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305296/4098275

```
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="/uploads/b6ed39d194c0a6b6e91322fb388908fa/myimage.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="overview" title="overview" href="http://www.example.com" coords="84,35,214,71" shape="rect">
</map>
```

#### Result

- image is visible in the markdown file
- when clicking the image, the browser is redirected to the source-file of the image

### Attempt 5 : PNG File - javascript detect click

```
<script>
function ClickRepsonse(){
alert ("clicked the image");
}
</script>

<img src="/img/myimage.png" onClick="ClickRepsonse()" />
```

#### Result

- image is visible in the markdown file
- when clicking the image, the browser is redirected to the source-file of the image

### Attempt 6 : inline image with html imagemap

- created inline image with https://www.base64-image.de/

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw......"
usemap="#image-map" >

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="_blank" alt="index" title="index" href="http://www.example.com" coords="0,0,100,100" shape="rect">
    </map>
```

#### Result

- image NOT visible in the markdown file on gitlab
- code works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abvjgwhy/)

## My Questions

- how can i make i clickable image in a markdown file on the gitlab -platform?
- Are there any other options to make a clickable image in a markdown